# Inheriting classes for a text-based game

Tags: java, class, inheritance, text, adventure

I'm trying to create a text-based game for class and i'm stuck on trying to get my main class, GCPUAPP, to read from my Artifact class.

Here's the code i've inputed for the GCPUAPP class:

```
Artifact artifact=new Artifact();
artifact.name="Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows";
artifact.description="Harry and his friends save the qizarding world again";
r1.contents=artifact;
dialog();
```

It's giving me an error on "new Artifact". Here's the code I have on Artifact:

```
public abstract class Artifact{ 

    String name, description;

    public String toString(){
        return name;
}
```

I'm new to Java so I am completely stuck.

Answer (score 4):

You can't create an instance of an abstract class `Artifact artifact=new Artifact();`

That is the point of abstract classes. Only non-abstract classes that inherit the abstract class can be instanced as object.

Either remove the `abstract` notation from your class definition, or create another class that inherits `Artifact` and call the constructor as this `Artifact artifact=new MyNewArtifact();`

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an instance of an abstract variable. So, `AbstractClass ac=new AbstractClass()` would throw a compile-time error.
Instead, you need another class to inherit from the abstract class.
For example:

```
public abstract class AbstractClassArtifact{ 

    String name, description;

    public String toString(){
        return name;
}
```

Then use:

```
 public class Artifact extends AbstractClassArtifact{
   public Artifact(String name, String description){ //Constructor to make setting variables easier
     this.name=name;
     this.description=description;
   }
 }
```

Finally create with:

```
 Artifact artifact=new Artifact("Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows", "Harry and his friends save the qizarding world again");
 r1.contents=artifact.toString();
 dialog();
```

Comment: The question is old and the last op  connection is `Feb 22 '11`.  but I upvote as good answer. However `artifact.toString();` would be more relevant if you use the returned result.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at how long ago it was. I've edited it so it uses the op's use of `toString()` now

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this

```
class HarryPotterArtifact extends Artifact {

    // no need to declare name and desc, they're inherited by "extends Artifact"

    public HarrayPotterArtifact(String name, String desc) {
         this.name = name;
         this.desc = desc;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
//Artifact artifact=new Artifact();
//artifact.name="Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows";
//artifact.description="Harry and his friends save the qizarding world again";

  String harryName = "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows";
  String harryDesc = "Harry and his friends save the qizarding world again";
  Artifact artifact = new HarryPotterArtifact(harryName,harryDesc);
```